# Set date and time is not displayed in textField / Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I created a UITextField and a datePicker as InputView. Everything works except the displaying of the set date and time.

This is my Code:

```
func setDatePickerAsInputView(target: Any, selector: Selector) {
        
        let screenWidht = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: screenWidht, height: 300))
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
        self.inputView = datePicker
        
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: screenWidht, height: 30.0))
        self.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        
        
    }

func setUpDateTextField() {
        
        //DateTextField
        dateTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        dateTextField.layer.borderWidth = 2
        dateTextField.textAlignment = .center
        self.dateTextField.setDatePickerAsInputView(target: self, selector: #selector(dateSelected))
        
        dateTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dateTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        dateTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        
        dateTextField.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    }
    
    @objc func dateSelected() {
        if let datePicker = self.dateTextField.inputView as? UIDatePicker {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
            self.dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
            dateTextField.text = "\(datePicker.date)"
        }
        
        self.dateTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        
    }
```

But if I close the datePicker it's still the current (old) date in the TextField and not the date and time I set. Can some help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have missed assign target to ````` UIDatePicker````. As you are passing target and selector but not assing to ````` UIDatePicker```

Add this line inside the `setDatePickerAsInputView` function

```
datePicker.addTarget(target, action: selector, for: .valueChanged)
```

Now, `dateSelected` method call everytime whenever value is changed. So, you need to remove this line `self.dateTextField.resignFirstResponder()` from function. Or you can change action from  `.valueChanged` to `.editingDidEnd`

Comment: Okay but now the date and timePicker disappears every time I change something, also when I'm not finish. And the textField just shows the correct date and not the time :(

Comment: @ChrisCode   self.dateTextField.resignFirstResponder() remove this line

Comment: Or change your action from .valueChanged to .editingDidEnd

Answer (score 0):

I have changed some line of code in **your code please look at once** and try it.  I took a one textfield and the name of that textfield is **txt_Date**

```
@IBOutlet weak var txt_Date: UITextField!
```

In **viewDidLoad** call below function

```
func setUpDateTextField() {
    //DateTextField
    txt_Date.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    txt_Date.layer.borderWidth = 2
    txt_Date.textAlignment = .center
    self.txt_Date.setDatePickerAsInputView(target: self, selector: #selector(opneDatePicker))
    
    txt_Date.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    txt_Date.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    txt_Date.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
}
```

Action for **date picker**

```
  @objc func opneDatePicker() {
    if let datePicker = self.txt_Date.inputView as? UIDatePicker {
        let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
        dateformatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dateformatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        self.txt_Date.text = dateformatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    }
    self.txt_Date.resignFirstResponder() }
```

For reuse and reduce the code of line , I make an **extension** of textfield which is come from **UITextField**

```
    extension UITextField {
    func setDatePickerAsInputView(target: Any, selector: Selector) {
        
        let screenWidht = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: screenWidht, height: 300))
        
        
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
          datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
          datePicker.sizeToFit()
        }
        
        self.inputView = datePicker
        
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: screenWidht, height: 44.0))
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: target, action: selector)
        toolBar.setItems([barButton], animated: false)
        self.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }}
```